# How to read secrets from /mnt/secret-store/DataAccessSettings--ConnectionSettings--ConnectionString

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

Im looking for how to load secrets from `/mnt/secret-store/DataAccessSettings--ConnectionSettings--ConnectionString`. My application doesn't have direct access to azure key vault the secrets have been stored in the pod in the /mnt/secret-store directory on the running pod.

All that works.  My issue is with how to get my C# application to pick up this settings.  I have looked all over and only found one example where someone was still using Configuration[connectionString] but I cant see how they have configured their application to load from that instead of loading from appsettings.json

Microsoft also appears to have a [couple of examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0) where you load directly from key valut, that is now what I need to do.

The only thing i can think of would be something like this which really seems wrong. I cant believe there is no way to directly load these into config

```
public string LoadSecret(string name)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(_pathToSecrets, name));

        return lines.FirstOrDefault(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l));
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to load it directly from KeyVault or are you still wanting to load it from a file?

Comment: Im looking for how to load secrets from /mnt/secret-store/DataAccessSettings--ConnectionSettings--ConnectionString.   My application doesnt have direct access to azure keyvault the secrets have been stored in the pod in the /mnt/secret-store directory.

Comment: OK, and what format is that file in? I'm assuming from your example it is just a file with the secret in it? Reason for asking is that there are multiple ways you could load this but want to make sure I suggest the correct one.

Comment: Thats the second problem I have not been able to figure that out either.  This seams to be some standard thing [Mount secrets, keys, and/or certs to a pod using a CSI volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver).   I can find loads of information on how to set it up but noting on how to use it.      I think i am looking for some kind of configuration builder which loads these files but i cant find anything.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method of mounting secrets I must say, but looking through that documentation I did notice something that might be of interest. If you look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver#set-environment-variables-to-reference-kubernetes-secrets) you will see a way of assigning secrets to environment variables. After that (assuming you're using .NET Core) you can easily get hold of those through `Configuration`

Comment: Yeah i saw that and i dont think its right SECRET_USERNAME and then hard coding the value in the Yaml file seems wrong.  Secrets are secrete they are not going to be written in a yaml file.  Maybe ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT but not thinks like password to RabbitMQ or the connection string to the database.  They need to come from the file on mnt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238896/discussion-between-deadwards-and-daimto).

Comment: Did a bit of checking from what i understand the file should just contain the value.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was unable to find one I ended up creating my own ConfigurationProvider

So now I can just add it this way

```
CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => { config.AddAzureMountedSecretStore(); })
                .Build().Run();
```

The main part of it just loads the file itself and sets the value of the contents of the file.

```
internal class AzureMntSecretStoreConfigurationFileParser
{
    private AzureMntSecretStoreConfigurationFileParser() { }

    public static KeyValuePair<string, string> Parse(string file)
        => new AzureMntSecretStoreConfigurationFileParser().ParseFile(file);

    private KeyValuePair<string, string> ParseFile(string file)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
        var secretName = fileName.Replace("--", ":");

        var value = File.ReadAllText(file);

        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(secretName, value);
    }

}
```

This way any new secrets added to the system will be loaded automatically by the when it runs rather than having to change the code itself.